# my multicolumn autocomplete work with just one letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ui autocomplete as a multi column autocomplete. The code is following

```js
$(function (){
                
   //value
            

var isi = [
                    {
                        jng: 'java',
                        wrn: 'write once run anywhere java',
                        tpe: 'bla',
                        kde: 'boh'
                    },
                    {
                        jng: 'PHP',
                        wrn: 'write once run anywhere PHP',
                        tpe: 'bli',
                        kde: 'bah'
                    }
                ];
                //code
                $('#name').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: isi,
                    focus: function (event, ui){
                        $('#name').val(ui.item.jng);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui){
                        $('#name').val(ui.item.kde);
                        return  false;
                    }
                })
    .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item){
      return $('<li>')
   .append("<a>" + item.jng + " " + item.wrn +  " " + item.tpe + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                        };
            });
```

```html
   

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <input id='name' type='text'/>
```

that's code just work if I type "j" or space on input. it's dissapeared again when I type another letter.
what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function (){
                
   //value
            

var isi = [
                    {
                        jng: 'java',
                        wrn: 'write once run anywhere java',
                        tpe: 'bla',
                        kde: 'boh'
                    },
                    {
                        jng: 'PHP',
                        wrn: 'write once run anywhere PHP',
                        tpe: 'bli',
                        kde: 'bah'
                    }
                ];
                //code
                $('#name').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 3,
                    source: isi,
                    focus: function (event, ui){
                        $('#name').val(ui.item.jng);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui){
                        $('#name').val(ui.item.kde);
                        return  false;
                    }
                })
    .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item){
      return $('<li>')
   .append("<a>" + item.jng + " " + item.wrn +  " " + item.tpe + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                        };
            });
```

```html
   

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <input id='name' type='text'/>
```

no item shown